# Маска для телефона jquery input mask. Диапазон чисел

Tags: jquery, inputmask

Сейчас используется такая маска для ввода телефона

```
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "+38(099) 999-9999"});
```

Можно ли как-то сделать проверку на запрет ввода оставшихся 2-х цифр в коде оператора на диапазон чисел
Например что бы можно было вводить только 063, 095 и т.д. ?

Comment: $("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(099) 999-9999"}); - так не помогает?

Comment: нет так были случаи что вводили два ноля подряд и номер терялся